# Getting php error in WooCommerce pre order extension

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can i resolve this issue, I'm getting the following error:

> array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in /wp-content/plugins/WooThemes_WooCommerce_Pre_Orders_v1_4_5/includes/admin/class-wc-pre-orders-admin-pre-orders.php on line 247

Here is the code where i am getting the error:

```
$action = $this->current_action();

// Get the set of orders to operate on.
$order_ids = isset( $_REQUEST['order_id'] ) ? array_map( 'absint', $_REQUEST['order_id'] ): array();

$message = $this->get_current_customer_message();
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Apparently the second  argument **`$_REQUEST['order_id']`** in array_map() function is not an array as it should be. Have you tried to use `echo var_dump($_REQUEST['order_id']);` to see what you get?

Comment: Pre-Order is a premium plugin. I'd advise you to contact Woo support. Especially, if there is a bug in the software.